# Cannot create a named range from an entire column in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps

I can't figure out how to create a named range from an entire column, i.e. "My Column" (A:A). When I use A1 notation to define the range, it simply sets the named range to the number of rows in the document:

```
function namedRange() {
  var active = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
  var range = active.getRange('B:B')
  active.setNamedRange('test', range)
}

// Result is a named range called "test" with the coordinates "B1:B1001"
```

Using the web UI, you can create a named range with "A:A" as the range and it captures the entire range, even if you add more rows.

Answer (score 0):

So far my solution to this is to simply set the range to a greater number of rows than the data will ever reach:

```
function namedRange() {
  var active = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
  var range = active.getRange('B1:B100000')
  active.setNamedRange('test', range)
}
```

If anyone posts a better answer I will gladly award them the green checkmark!